# How to add an <em> to toplinks in Magento

Tags: magento

Is there a way to edit the customer.xml file to add an  tag to My account link from header?

I want something like this:

```
  <ul class="links">
     <li class="first"><a href="wish" title="WISHLIST">WISHLIST</a></li>
     <li class="has-arrow"><a href="myaccount" title="MY ACCOUNT">MY ACCOUNT <em class="sprite arrow-s type-1"></em></a></li>
     <li class="last"><a href="logout" title="LOGOUT">LOGOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
```

If it can't be done from customer.XML what file should I edit? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently you can't use in customer.xml something like `<liParams>` or `<beforeText>`. If you go in /base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml (the template file responsibile for rendering the links) you will see these lines:

```
<li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>>
  <?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>>
    <?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?>
  </a>
  <?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?>
</li>
```

So before the closing tag `</a>` it's only the label. So in order to add the `<em>` I've modified the code using this:

```
<li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>>
  <?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>>
    <?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?>
    <?php echo ($_link['label'] == 'My Account') ? '<em class="sprite arrow-s type-1"></em>' : '' ?>
  </a>
  <?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?>
</li>
```